# I need perfect mysql query to get result as i want

Tags: mysql

i have created sql fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6015c6/2

My table schema are as under :

```
> assignedattributeid (TABLE)
>     id INT(10)
>     productid INT(10)
>     attributeid INT(10)
> 
> products (TABLE)
>     id INT(10)
>     productname VARCHAR(50)
```

Suppose records are as under :

Table : assignedattributeid

```
id  productid   attributeid
1   5   10
2   5   11
3   6   11
4   7   10
```

Table : Products

```
id  productname
5   P1000
6   P2000
7   P3000
```

Actually i want to get all those products where both attributeid 10 and 11 are assigned.

> I use this query : select distinct products.* from  products left
>   join assignedattributeid on assignedattributeid.productid=products.id
>   where assignedattributeid.attributeid in (10,11)

But it does not work. It shows all records. Actually it should show only P1000 product.

Any suggestion in query ?

Comment: Certainly you get all entries, since `assignedattributeid.attributeid in (10,11)` does match all entries. Why would you expect to select only P1000 products?

Comment: @arkascha - "**both** attributeid 10 and 11 are assigned".

Comment: Actually i need only those product where both attributeid (ie 10 and 11) must be assigned. If any one is matched then it should not return.  In my project i have created a checkbox of attribute id. So if user select any multiple checkbox then only those products should show where selected checkbox are selected.    In my project checkbox value will be 10, 11 which i have used in given fiddle sample

Comment: Don't you have primary/unique keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select distinct products.productname as sid from  products
left join assignedattributeid on assignedattributeid.productid=products.id
where assignedattributeid.attributeid in (10,11)
group by sid having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` *and* `GROUP BY`!?

Comment: Any time you see DISTINCT and GROUP BY in a query, at the very least, an alarm bell should start ringing. Furthermore, `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x` negates the outer join

Answer (score 3):

Group by products and add a `HAVING` condition which counts unique attributeids - it must be 2.

```
select products.* from  products
join assignedattributeid on assignedattributeid.productid=products.id
where assignedattributeid.attributeid in (10,11)
group by products.id
having count(distinct assignedattributeid.attributeid) = 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6015c6/11

Or join the `assignedattributeid` table once per `attributeid`

```
select distinct products.* from  products
join assignedattributeid a1 on a1.productid=products.id
join assignedattributeid a2 on a2.productid=products.id
where a1.attributeid = 10
  and a2.attributeid = 11
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6015c6/8

If `products.id` is primary key and `assignedattributeid(productid, attributeid)` is a unique key, you don't need the `DISCTINCT` keyword.

Comment: @MatBailie - I added a working sqlfiddle-demo - just for you :-)

Comment: I think there is something wrong in query, because there is not fix number of attributeid. You can see that i have added one more record in assignedattributedid at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bb31/2      . So i try to search record with attributeid 10,11 and 12. Then it does not work.

Comment: @user3264863 - you also added a condition which can never be true because `a2.attributeid` can't be 11 and 12 at same time for one row. If the number is not fixed, take the first query or add a join for every number.

Comment: I think your first query may work where i may need to assigned number of attributeid query dynamically.

Comment: Fixed sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bb31/6 - While the first solution looks more flexible, the second one might be faster.

Comment: Thanks for your tips